# How to remove an invisible space between div tags

Tags: html, css

I have built several web sites and now i am having newbie problem that is driving me nuts...

**Here's my code:**

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="page_wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>
    </div><!-- end #header --> 

    <div id="main_menu">
        <p>Here goes the main menu</p>
    <div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>
    </div><!-- end #main_menu --> 

    <div id="left">
    </div><!-- end #left -->
```

**And here's my CSS**

First i have a CSS Reset template from here:
http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css

and then on another file:

```
body, html {
    font: 10pt Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
}
div {
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
#page {

}
#page_wrapper {

}
#main_menu {

}
#left {

}
div.clear_both {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

And on the link below there is an image screenshot on which you can see the output... (i am working on a local server)

There is an unexplainable space between the div tags I CANT REMOVE IT and it is driving me nuts... please can someone tell me how to remove it?
I have tryed adding a negative top margin but from my previous experience it is not a solution... usualy seting the margin and the padding to 0 was enough... somehow now it is diferent :S

[image]

[Unexplainable DIV space](http://makedonskarabota.com/gallery/div_space.png)

Comment: I usually use a `<br style="clear: both;"/>` for what I think you're doing, although I'm not sure you need it here. Also, I guess I'm not sure what space you're referring to?

Comment: I am refering to the space between:

Heading 1
 

Here goes the main menu
 
 
Heading 2

............
when i select it there is some sort of invisible lines there..

also the space exits even if i remove those 
<div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div> so that is not a solution either :S

Comment: If I thought it was the solution, I would have posted it as an answer. :) You don't need the DIV with an encoded space to accomplish that, so you can simplify it by using a BR. It would be more useful if you would post a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrated the problem with full css/html you're using.

Comment: I much prefer `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: visible` on the parent container instead of `clear: both` elements all over the place. Does the trick pretty much everywhere you'd use a clear div.

Comment: @deceze - That's an interesting approach. How does that do what clear accomplishes?

Comment: @Jared A parent container does not by default grow to accommodate the height of floating elements, that's what you usually use clearing elements for. Setting an `overflow` value triggers the container to evaluate whether it needs to hide something or show scrollbars or such. If there are no other restrictions on its height, that will cause it to first grow as large as it can before it decides to hide the contents. Or so the technical explanation goes...

Comment: @Jared No, tall. Width is not influenced by floating children. (I love technical terms like *floating children* … ;))

Comment: @deceze - Maybe my understanding of clear is not... clear. I always interpreted what was happening was it was "filling" the space left/right/both so that the next element flowed below the preceding floated element.

Comment: @Jared `clear` just pushes the clearing element *below* all floating elements within the same context. Width doesn't matter. The way it is used here is to place it below the floating `<h1>` (assuming `<h1>` is actually floated). The parent container will accommodate this *non-floating element* in its height calculation. The end effect is that the parent grows in height to include the non-floating element, which happens to be below the floating element, which achieves the effect of wrapping the parent container around the floating element. The same can be done with `overflow`.

Comment: @deceze - Right! That makes sense. I was all sideways on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've finaly found the problem thanks to all of You but especialy thanks to Notepad++

**The problem was caused by the invisible blank spaces (from the SPACE key).** 
I don't know why, but according to my knowlege this is the first time multiple space strokes to be detected by the browser.. I guess the newer browsers now are registerng more then one blank space after another.

I just opened the html scripts with Notepad++ and set from View->Show Simbol->Show All Characters. Then i've deleted all of the unneccessery empty spaces and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
div {line-height: 1;}
h1, p {margin: 0;}
```

don't use units for your line height, see: [**Unitless line-heights**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/) for more information,

if you simply put `1.4` then the line height will be `1.4 x the font-size`, this should help you get control of your gaps, obviously my code example above absolutely zero's everything and is just an example

#### JSFiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/avSqK/)

Comment: The OP is ostensibly using a reset template.

Comment: yes, true, I have just added a fiddle to show how those two bits of code work, without a reset. I know the reset should reset the margins, but perhaps the code we can't see is re-adding some? or perhaps the reset is the issue, as we can't test the whole page I just went from basics

Comment: While that's true, the actual code the OP posted doesn't demonstrate the issue either, so my assumption is there's something else going on that they have not included. See my second comment on the question.

Comment: I have completely removed those div tags:
<div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>

so now my code looks like:

<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="page_wrapper">

 <div id="header">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 </div><!-- end #header --> 

 <div id="main_menu">
  <p>Here goes the main menu</p>
 </div><!-- end #main_menu --> 
 
 <div id="left">
 </div><!-- end #left --> 

but the gaps are still there..

here is an image screenshot from my code now:
http://makedonskarabota.com/gallery/div2.png

Comment: @Spirit what's the CSS for `div#main_menu`? we need more of your actual CSS, like a [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) example you can put in your `html.css` and `style.css` and paste your HTML and use the "normalise css" checkbox for the reset. I think you have 2 resets -  an HTML5 one as well?

Comment: OK... here's the example as you told me to do so:  http://jsfiddle.net/m54Ce/ .. The whole code.. on the CSS field first is the CSS Reset and after that its my CSS... ...

On http://jsfiddle.net looks OK.. but on my local it is still screwed up as it is on the screenshot.. i am getting despair.. :'(

Comment: Or perhaps it is the Firefox version (4.0.1) that is screwing the things... but i have run the code on Chrome and it is the same problem there too :S

Comment: @Spirit,OK here's a fiddle (which looks OK!) [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/ujHrp/) - can you fill in the missing CSS for #page, #page_wrapper, #main_menu, #main_content (though I've put a little guess in for that) - also fill in *any* CSS (apart from the reset) for `h1, h2 etc` too ;)

Comment: I've finaly found the problem thanks to Notepad++

The problem was caused by the invisible blank spaces (from the SPACE key). I don't know why but this is the first time and they where detected by the browser.. *I guess the newer browsers now are registerng more then one blank space after another.*

**I just opened the html scripts with Notepad++ and set from View->Show Simbol->Show All Characters. Then i've deleted all of the unneccessery empty spaces and that solved my problem.**

Comment: Please can someone post my previous comment (above) as an answer so that anyone with a similar problem can avid a frustration like this :) .. I am a new user and cant post this as an answer to the problem for at least 8 hours.. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 4):

In top of your CSS file just paste this

> `* {
>   margin: 0; padding: 0;
>   }`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to nag (especially seeing as this is your first answer on SO) but this really isn't a neat solution, if it is a solution at all. It'd be the css-equivalent of dropping a nuke to kill a fruit fly.

Comment: @posdef It's not an answer to the question, but it's perfectly elegant if you *want* to remove margin/padding on all elements (unless otherwise specified.) Specific CSS rules will still take precedence.

Comment: A poor solution.  This will affect everything styled within the document.  Headings, Lists, Body, etc.  This should be avoided and only the elements which are causing the undesired appearance should be styled this way.

Comment: YUI reset is already taking care of the reset, according to OP. Probably better than this reset-too-many-things

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="clear_both" />&nbsp;</div>
```

This is creating you a white space between Heading 1 and Here goes the main menu...

DIVs comes one below other if you have them "display: block", so even if this div don't have text, it has empty space " "...

If you delete this, all other will be like text below...

Sorry if I understand something wrong... ;)

Comment: Remove this div I mentioned in post here, and add in div with id header style="line-height: 1em;" or even smaller size if you want smaller space between...

Answer (score 0):

`div {line-height: 1.4em;}` should be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

on your DIV or image use:

```
.div
{
display: inline-block;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

and on body use:

```
body
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

I had the same problem and this worked just fine for me I just got it fixed! Hope this helps anyone searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Div comes with blank spaces whenever used.
In order to remove them

Use

```
margin-top: -10px
```

or whatever is convenient to your page setup.