# Unwanted space below header and body element and above footer

Tags: html, css

I have a space about 10px below the header and above the footer on this site. http://www.ankordivelights.com/ . I have set every margin I can find to 0px and google inspect element is not showing margin. I have restricted the header, body and footer to 1220 px. Any thoughts on where the problem lies?

Comment: You seem to have a `<style>` tag for the `<header>` in the HTML *after* the  `<header>`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Paulie_D The site uses Opencart which uses php to load template files for header, I embedded style into home.tpl because I need to overwrite standard page and display a background that includes a kind of 'splash screen' with a product image. the other inner pages have a small header simply showing light showing through the sea-water.

Answer (score 1):

For the header gap:

```
header {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

For the footer gap:

```
.title-footer h3 {
    margin-top:0px;
}
address {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

---

### **Reason:**

**Header:** The gap is caused either by:

1. Unnecessary white-space or line-breaks after the closing  tag. Move your `<style>....</style>` to your `<head>....</head>` and remove uncessary white-space and line-breaks. (Similar issue: [How to remove an invisible space between div tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905306/how-to-remove-an-invisible-space-between-div-tags))
2. No specified height was given to the `<header>....</header>` except for a `min-height`. The background-image is using a background-size value of 100%. That means 100% of it's parent div's height, not it's min-height. Just add an `overflow:hidden` or specify a height of any value lesser than your `min-height` value (0px - 580px) and it should work fine.

---

**Footer:** The gap is caused by the default `margin-top` of your h3 tag from here:

```
<div class="title-footer">
    <h3>Need help?</h3>
</div>
```

And the default `margin-bottom` from your `<address>` tag from here:

```
<div class="bottom_footer">
    <address class="copyright">Anchor Dive Lights © 2015  |  All Rights Reserved</address>
</div>
```